# Can't access keys in JSON output: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json

I am struggling trying to extract keys from a `JSON` output.

requests outputs this `JSON`:

```
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":[{"id":"USERID","name":"USERNAME"}]}
```

at this point I get rid of "for (;;);" in order to get a valid JSON:

```
json_header = (data.text).replace('for (;;);', '')
```

Now I need to print USERID and USERNAME. This is what I try:

```
json_data = json.dumps(json_header)
json_objects = json.loads(json_data)

print(json_objects['payload']['id'])
```

But I get this:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Can you help me fix the code?

Comment: `print(json_objects['payload'][0]['id'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what the relation between `json_header` and `json_data` is.
But if your json is

```
{"__ar":1,"payload":[{"id":"USERID","name":"USERNAME"}]}
```

so `payload` is an array of dicts. To access the first (and only) dict in the array you do:

```
payload = json_objects['payload']
first_elemet = payload[0]
id = first_element['id']
print(id)
```

or all together, complete and ready to execute:

```
import json
json_string = '{"__ar":1,"payload":[{"id":"USERID","name":"USERNAME"}]}'
json_objects = json.loads(json_string)
print(json_objects['payload'][0]['id'])
```

---

By the way: your original data with the for loop looks scary. If this should be JSON it is strange at least and looks like a bug in whatever backend you are calling.

Comment: Thanks for being so fast in answering. Unfortunately, it still gives me the same error. I know the code is scary. Infact it is not actually supposed to be called with request...

Comment: I tested it the way I understand your code (see updated answer). If this does not work, please paste a complete runable snippet to reproduce the error.